# kivy cannot import name 'palette'

Tags: python, kivy

I am getting weird import error while running kivy code. How can I fix this?

file:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green" # "Purple", "Red"

        screen = Screen()
        screen.add_widget(
            MDRectangleFlatButton(
                text="Hello, World",
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
        )
    )
    return screen

MainApp().run()
```

error:

```
     from kivymd.color_definitions import palette, hue, text_colors
 ImportError: cannot import name 'palette'
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in kivymd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error if you are using python 3.8 version. Downgrading to 3.7 version will help

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my system and it worked fine, are you using the latest version of `KivyMD` from `GitHub`?

Also, in order to resolve the error, please follow the instructions below

1. Go to the `kivymd` folder
2. Open the `color_definitions.py` file
3. Make sure that the three lists - `palette`, `hue`, `text_colors` are present.

if not, paste the following in the `color_definitions.py` file and save it

```
palette = [
    "Red",
    "Pink",
    "Purple",
    "DeepPurple",
    "Indigo",
    "Blue",
    "LightBlue",
    "Cyan",
    "Teal",
    "Green",
    "LightGreen",
    "Lime",
    "Yellow",
    "Amber",
    "Orange",
    "DeepOrange",
    "Brown",
    "Gray",
    "BlueGray",
]


hue = [
    "50",
    "100",
    "200",
    "300",
    "400",
    "500",
    "600",
    "700",
    "800",
    "900",
    "A100",
    "A200",
    "A400",
    "A700",
]


text_colors = {
    "Red": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Pink": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "FFFFFF",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Purple": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "FFFFFF",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "DeepPurple": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "FFFFFF",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Indigo": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "FFFFFF",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Blue": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "LightBlue": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Cyan": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "000000",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "Teal": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "Green": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "LightGreen": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "000000",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "Lime": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "000000",
        "700": "000000",
        "800": "000000",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "Yellow": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "000000",
        "700": "000000",
        "800": "000000",
        "900": "000000",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "Amber": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "000000",
        "700": "000000",
        "800": "000000",
        "900": "000000",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "Orange": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "000000",
        "700": "000000",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "000000",
        "A700": "000000",
    },
    "DeepOrange": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "000000",
        "A200": "000000",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Brown": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "FFFFFF",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "FFFFFF",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "Gray": {
        "50": "FFFFFF",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "000000",
        "500": "000000",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "FFFFFF",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
    "BlueGray": {
        "50": "000000",
        "100": "000000",
        "200": "000000",
        "300": "000000",
        "400": "FFFFFF",
        "500": "FFFFFF",
        "600": "FFFFFF",
        "700": "FFFFFF",
        "800": "FFFFFF",
        "900": "FFFFFF",
        "A100": "FFFFFF",
        "A200": "FFFFFF",
        "A400": "FFFFFF",
        "A700": "FFFFFF",
    },
}
```